# MATLAB make text plotted on figure bold

Tags: matlab

**Is there a way I can make the text that I have added to my graph bold?**

I added the text using:

```
text(9,2  , '1,296 atoms', 'Color', 'k');
```

However, the text is faint and it is hard to see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `FontWeight` property.

```
text(0.1,0.5  , 'normal', 'Color', 'k');
text(0.5,0.5  , 'bold', 'Color', 'k', 'FontWeight', 'bold');
```

[image]

In general, if you want to view the editable properties of a plot type you can do a simple call:

```
t = text(0.5, 0.5, 'a')
get(t)
```

This will show you all of the editable properties. It is then a bit easier to search the MathWorks page for the values you want to set them to.

More information about `text` properties can be found here: http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/text_props.html